# Eclipse function are all locked

Tags: eclipse

I don't understand why all function in Eclipse are locked. I can't do anything: (file, edit, source,..) all locked.
I've already tried to restart and everything but still doesn't work, any suggestion?

Comment: What version of Eclipse? What operating system? What version of Java? If this is Eclipse on macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) and your system language is not English see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170925criticalbug.php)

Comment: Ok, thanks.. that was my problem